# VB.NET 2010 Conversion Errors

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to convert a VB.NET 2005 I inherited to 2010. Right now, the majority of the errors I get during building are: Sub XXX or Property XXX "has multiple definitions with identical signatures". They're all in the same file called AssetsReport.Designer.vb. However, they aren't all exact copies. They will change a little and they are in different classes.

I've worked with ASP.NET, but that was written from scratch. I'm at a bit of a loss on how to proceed here.

The file in question is too large to post here, but you can download it [here](http://www.raventech2099.com/temp/AssetsReport.Designer.vb.txt) if you want to look at it.

Thanks

Comment: Well thats an awful lot of code, how abouts you isolate a section that causes the error by its self, and post that

Comment: It's not one error, it's over 100 errors. Every time there's a sub with the same name. Even though they're in different classes. I can add more details in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the header of the code you posted:

`This code was generated by a tool.`

You need to recreate the dataset in Visual Studio

have a look at [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/4d56e1/how-to-create-a-strongly-typed-dataset/) on how to do this